# Is there a way to have an Word 2007 template automatically update a date with the current date?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2007

I would like to make my template `template.dotx` capable of adding the current date every time I open it.

Is this possible using MS Word 2007 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can insert a `field` with the current date as explained [e.g. here](https://askdrexel.drexel.edu/app/answers/detail/a_id/2368/~/how-to%3A-insert-date-and-time-in-a-document-in-word-2007.), then save your template.

> Microsoft Word enables you to insert Date and Time in a document. It indicates the date and time of the creation of the document. Various date and time formats are available. Date and Time can be inserted in all pages in a document. The date and time can be placed anywhere on the document.
>
> To insert date and time in a document:
>
> 1. Open Microsoft Word document (in your case the template file).
> 2. Click the 'Insert' tab. (The 'Insert' tab appears.)
> 3. From the 'Text' group, click the 'Quick Parts' drop-down list.
> 4. Click 'Field'. (The 'Field' dialog box appears.)
> 5. From the 'Categories' drop-down list, select 'Date and Time'. (The 'Date and Time' properties appear.)
> 6. From the 'Field names' list, click 'CreateDate'.
> 7. From the 'Date formats' list, select the appropriate format.
> 8. From the 'Field names' list, click 'Time'.
> 9. From the 'Date formats' list, select the appropriate format.
> 10. Click 'OK'.

You may want to read more directly on [the help of office](https://support.office.com/en-in/article/Insert-and-format-field-codes-in-Word-2007-1c27736e-9624-45da-946c-2b3050a9491f) on the Microsoft site.